# Is it possible for a thread to starve at wait() loop?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, synchronized

Suppose I have this method

```
/*1*/    public synchronized void method1() throws InterruptedException {
    
            while (condition)
 /*2*/           wait();


  /*3*/      notify();
      }
```

Suppose, we have a `Thread 1` on the 2nd line wait condition, so Thread 1 would be in state `WAITING`.

Now `Thread 2` enters, it doesn't satisfy the condition, so it bypasses the while loop and then `Thread 2` calls `notify` in line 3, then `Thread 1` should change its state from `WAITING` to `BLOCKED`, until the `Thread 2` exits completely.

Suppose now, before Thread 2 exits completely, `Thread 3` is `BLOCKED` outside the synchronized block to acquire the monitor.

Is it possible that `Thread 3` acquires the lock before `Thread 1` ? Can it be the same for `Thread 4`, and `Thread 5` and so on? In that case, `Thread-1` would be in the starving state.

Is this conceptually possible?

EDIT: How do I prevent starvation if this is the case?

Comment: Short answer: yes. What are you trying to achieve with this construct?

Comment: @Fildor Is there a way to let the thread in the wait loop acquire first? How do I prevent starvation here?

Comment: Well, there is not enough information to give a solid suggestion. We'd need to know a little more about the `condition` and what you are actually trying to do. Maybe it's easier _and_ thread-safe(er) doing it completely differently? But to tell that, I'd need to know what "it" is.

Comment: @user16320675 or maybe it's better to invert the logic. The _thread_ shouldn't wait at all. If whatever _data_ isn't ready to be processed, yet, it shouldn't be processed and put back into some sort of queue... but it's completely unkown if that is applicable to the problem OP is trying to solve.

Comment: @user16320675 Exactly. And your guess isn't wrong. But all we can do is 'guess' until OP clearifies...

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity! I guess this would answer my question. I was just wondering if maybe there is any way for the first thread which goes to the blocked state to get the highest priority. The reentrant lock with fairness would work in this case, I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I prevent starvation if this is the case?

You cannot prevent it using `synchronized` keyword. However, you can use `ReentrantLock` instead because it allows "fair" locking

```
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true); // fair lock
private final Condition sync = lock.newCondition();

public void method1() throws InterruptedException {
   lock.lock();
   try {
     while (condition)
       sync.await();
     sync.signal(); 
   } finally {
     lock.unlock();
   }
}
```

Keep in mind, that fair lock comes at price and you should have real reasons to use it

From JavaDoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html

> The constructor for this class accepts an optional fairness parameter. When set true, under contention, locks favor granting access to the longest-waiting thread. Otherwise this lock does not guarantee any particular access order. Programs using fair locks accessed by many threads may display lower overall throughput (i.e., are slower; often much slower) than those using the default setting, but have smaller variances in times to obtain locks and guarantee lack of starvation. Note however, that fairness of locks does not guarantee fairness of thread scheduling. Thus, one of many threads using a fair lock may obtain it multiple times in succession while other active threads are not progressing and not currently holding the lock. Also note that the untimed tryLock method does not honor the fairness setting. It will succeed if the lock is available even if other threads are waiting.